# Accept input on 1 key press instead of waiting for user to press enter on Console.ReadLine()

Tags: c#, console-application

I am working on a c# Console Application where the user has to only enter a number to make a selection. Instead of making the user have to type in the number and then hit enter is there a way for the input to be accept on just the number not being inputted, i.e. so the user doesn't have to press enter.e

Thanks for your help.

Comment: come on, this could have been googled. j/k, Console.ReadKey() is what you're after

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Console.ReadKey() should work in this case

Answer (score 7):

[`Console.ReadKey()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.readkey.aspx)